# Promoting all fields in InfoPath to SharePoint

Tags: infopath, forms-services

This is probably more of an InfoPath 2007 question, but ultimately I've created a form with 180 fields in it (don't ask, customer requirement) and ultimately I'm wondering is there an easy way to just promote everything for use by SharePoint in a minimum amount of clicks.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry.  I'm afraid you have to one-at-a-time it in the publishing wizard.

Comment: Sad but true...